# trying to understand how @JoinTable and @JoinColumn works

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I am learning hibernate and stuck a bit with the below problem

have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE department (
 department_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 caption varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE employee (
 employee_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 fio varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 fk_department_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (fk_department_id) REFERENCES department (department_id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

and two classes (in the first class commented out code looks like working solution)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {
....
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_department_id", referencedColumnName = "department_id") })
    /*
     * @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department", cascade =
     * CascadeType.ALL)
     */
    public Set<Employee> getEmployies() {
        return employees;
    }
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
......
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_department_id")
    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
```

this results into

```
INFO: HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK3cspe1b06hmsik5l8y1i11xmd:employee [employies_employee_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (employee [fk_department_id,employies_employee_id])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:130)
```

Please help me to understand why this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The following should work just fine.  You'll notice I am not specifying any join column relations because I am allowing Hibernate to generate those automatically for me.

```
@Entity
public class Department {
  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "department_employees")
  private List<Employee> employees;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
  @ManyToOne
  private Department department;
}
```

But lets assume you want to be explicit about the join columns.

```
@Entity
public class Department {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "department_id")
  private Integer id;
  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(
     name = "department_employees",
     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "department_id"),
     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"))
  private List<Employee> employees;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "employee_id")
  private Integer id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinTable(
     name = "department_employees",
     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", insertable = false, updatable = false))
  private Department department;
}
```

The key points to take away from this are:

- The name of the join table specifies the middle table that maintains the relationship between the `Department` and `Employee` entities.  It should not refer to the `Employee` table as your code illustrates.
- The `joinColumns` attribute represents the primary key attributes of the containing entity, in this case that is `Department`, hence I used `department_id`.
- The `inverseColumns` attribute represents the primary key attributes of the associated entity, in this case that is `Employee`, hence I used `employee_id`.

Update:

If you'd like to eliminate the `@JoinTable` and merely maintain the relationship between `Department` and `Employee`, you'd change your mappings as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Department {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
  private List<Employee> employees;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
  @ManyToOne
  private Department department;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Naros for the answer,
in my case i don't have a middle table, i have 2 tables only

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't want a JoinTable then.  You could easily map the OneToMany and ManyToOne without a JoinTable if you'd like then.  Updated by post to include the relation mapping without a JoinTable.

Comment: Do i understand correctly that JoinTable with JoinColumn works when i have 3 tables?

Comment: anyone knows how to use JoinTable for 2 tables having onetomany relationship?